# Restore original LightDM Greeter preinstalled with Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: unity, desktop-environments, 14.10

When I login to ubuntu, I get a menu in the top right corner to load Ubuntu environment.

This means that the lightdm greeter is corrupt. I tried to locate the lightdm.conf but I can't find it and read some where it's deprecated.

All I need is to restore it where I have 2 users with different backgrounds + Guest + No Grid